# Azure DevOps Pipelene doesn't compile .netstandard 2.0 projects

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, .net-standard-2.0

I'm stuck in a rut with this proble. After converting some solution projects in .netstandard 2.0 the pipeline doesn't compile. Other are .NET Framework 4.8 projects.

Here the errors

> Installed SDKs: No .NET SDKs were found.
>
> Install the [6.0.400] .NET SDK or update
> [E:\myApplicationFolder\global.json] to match an installed SDK.
>
> Download a .NET SDK: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

I tried the following steps:

1. installed VS 2022 and tells to the pipeline to use VS 2022 msbuild
2. installed the .NET sdk
3. created the global.json choerent with the solution
4. checked the environment variables (they point to C:\Program Files\dotnet)
5. checked the version of .NET SDK

This is the global.json

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.400"
  }
}
```

There are the configuration on the pipeline

[image]

I don't have any troubles building the solution with msbuild from powershell.

Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the pipeline definition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many problems, Azure DevOps isn't updated to the latest version and can't manage .NET 6.0 solutions. I had to specify the msbuild of VS 2022 also to restore nuget packages